How can I tell if a phrase has the function of an adjective, adverb, preposition, etc.?
The phrase 'call it a day' has the function of a verb. It acts as a and replaces a verb.

Let's call it a day - Let's eat
I called it a day - I yawned
It's time to call it a day - It's time to eat

The phrase 'coffee shop' has the function of a noun. It acts as a and replaces a noun.

I went to the coffee shop - I went to the cinema
Coffee shops are often quiet - Libraries are often quiet

These examples are easy for me, but others are difficult. How can I tell if the following phrases act as adjectives, adverbs, prepositions or maybe something else?

in love: collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-love
not all roses: dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-all-roses
on display: ldoceonline.com/dictionary/on-display
on one's hands and knees: merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20one%27s%20hands%20and%20knees
in someone's opinion: collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-someones-opinion
in two minds: merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20two%20minds


What if the phrase has the function of a phrase?

@TimR. This is not possible in my distinction. However, it can have a function of an interjection like 'fear not' or function of a sentence like 'I think not'

In love describes someone's state and is hence adjectival.
Not all roses describes a situation or life in general and is adjectival.
Something on display is in a public place where people can look at it; the phrase is adjectival.
On one's hands and knees as in she went down on her hands and knees describes how she did it  and is adverbial.
In someone's opinion is adverbial.
In two minds describes someone's state as not decided or certain about something and is hence adjectival.

You're doing it wrong.  Noun phrases are called that because they are headed by a noun, not because the "have the function of a noun".  This is important because nouns have many functions, including "like adjectives".
Noun phrases are headed by nouns, "coffee shop" is headed by "shop".  In fact it is a compound noun, since "coffee" is also a noun (a noun adjunct)
Verbs head verb phrases. "Call it a day" is a verb phrase headed by the verb "call"  (I know that's a verb because it has tenses etc)
"In love" is a prepositional phrase, headed by the preposition "in", as are most of the others in your list.  The only exception is "not all roses", which is a noun phrase, headed by the noun "roses".
You can use prepositional phrases in many ways in a sentence. Only when you use a PP in a sentence can you say if it is "adjectival" or "adverbial".
Don't get mixed up with the word "phrase".  It has two meanings.  One is "syntactic phrase", which is how it is used in grammar.  The other meaning is a "common expression or saying - an idiom or proverb"  The dictionary lists "common expressions".  These might no be syntactic phrases.

I've never written about 'verb phrases' or 'noun phrases' or 'prepositional phrases'. I've deliberately avoided these terms.

My point, then, is that you can't tell if a phrase is modifying a noun or an verb, until you put it in a sentence.  I can take a PP like "in love" and use it as a "fronted adverbial" or as the complement in a SVC sentence, or to modify a noun, like an adjective.  This means that your question is meaningless!  The phrase "in love" can be like an adjective, noun or adverb.

But I don't want to know if a phrase is modifying a noun or a verb. I want to know if a phrase act as a noun, a verb, an adverb or an adjective

Also, I don't think that 'in love' can be used like a noun. 'I bought an apple' is grammatically correct. 'I bought an in love.' is not.

Depends what you mean by "like a noun".  Nouns can do a lot of things! The can be complements in SVC sentences "He is a boy"   (boy is a noun)  "He is in love"  (in love is a PP)  the PP "in love" is in exactly the same context as the NP "a boy", so  "in love" is "like a noun".....

So "act like a noun" is meaningless!

No, it's not. Just because you can swap one phrase for another in one context doesn't mean you can swap it in others. For something to act as a noun it must be able to replace another noun in any context so that the sentence will be grammatically correct. Give me one noun that can always be replaced by 'in love'. You can't so 'in love' doesn't act as a noun.

For example, I know that 'call it a day' acts as a verb because it can always be replaced by an intransitive verb such as 'yawn'.

Sorry,  grammar doesn't work like that.

Grammar does work like that

'in love' probably acts as an adjective + there is a phrase (that act a verb BTW) 'fall in love' where it acts as an adverb

OP's query on phrase analysis:

How can I tell if the following phrases act as adjectives, adverbs, prepositions, or something else?

Understanding phrase functions is crucial for effective communication.
Methods to analyze phrases and determine their function in a sentence:

Identify the phrase's position in the sentence (syntax)
Determine its relationship with surrounding words (semantics).
Try replacing the phrase with a single word of a known type.

Examples of phrases and their functions:

1. in love (Adjective Phrase).
Romeo was in love - replace with "happy".
Romeo fell in love - replace with "quickly" (adverb phrase)
.
2. not all roses (Adjective Phrase).
Being in a relationship is not all roses - replace with "difficult"
.
3. on display (Adjective Phrase).
The musical talent on display is impressive - replace with "visible"
.
4. on one's hands and knees (Adverb Phrase).
She went down on her hands and knees - replace with "carefully"
.
5. in someone's opinion (Adverb Phrase).
The book is, in Henry's opinion, the best on the subject - replace with "personally"
.
6. in two minds (Adjective Phrase).
I'm in two minds about hiring him - replace with "undecided"

